# CNContactPicker - all contacts are greyed out

Tags: macos, swift

I can't seem to get CNContactPicker to work.  I've watched and rewatched WWDC session 223.  It looks like for the iOS version of the picker, there's a predicate you set to enable contacts for selection, but the OS X version has no equivalent.  From what I understand, if your delegate supports contactPicker(picker: CNContactPicker, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) and you don't supply any displayedKeys, the picker will be configured to select contacts.  Here's sample code.  When I use this, the contacts are all greyed out and the delegate method is never called.

Thanks in advance

```
func selectContact() {  

    let contactStore = CNContactStore(  
    contactStore.requestAccessForEntityType(CNEntityType.Contacts, completionHandler:{(bool: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in  
        print("access granted = \(bool)")  
    })  

    let contactPicker = CNContactPicker()  
    contactPicker.delegate = self  
    contactPicker.showRelativeToRect(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 500), ofView: view, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.MinX)  

}  

//Delegate method  
func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPicker, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) {  
    print(contact)  
}
```

Comment: Do you have access granted? (Not that this should matter; on iOS, you don't need access to use the picker.)

Comment: Another possibility is that this thing is just broken. A lot of Contacts UI stuff _is_ broken on iOS, so why should OS X share the pain? :)

Comment: When I run this, the print command returns true.  I have this there to verify it's not an access issue.  Interesting about a lot of Contacts UI stuff being broken; it's making me think there may not be a current solution for the picker problem :|

Comment: I have just tested the picker and it works. However you are right that the contacts are greyed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a memory-management issue with `CNContactPicker`. I managed to get this working by keeping a reference to it in an outside scope:

```
let picker = CNContactPicker()

@IBAction func import(sender: NSButton) {
    picker.delegate = self

    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    contactStore.requestAccessForEntityType(CNEntityType.Contacts, completionHandler:{(bool: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        print("access granted = \(bool)")
        if bool {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self. picker.showRelativeToRect(sender.frame, ofView: sender.superview ?? self.view, preferredEdge: .MaxY)
            }
        }
    })
}

func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPicker, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) {
    picker.close()
    print("Chose contact \(contact)!")
}
```

Note that everything still looks greyed out (maybe it's supposed to look like that?) but at least the delegate methods are called.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll bet there's some hook to a predicate that they forgot in the API for Mac.  It seems in iOS, you set the predicate to make them not greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same problem. After doing some research you can enable which contacts are available and which aren't.

Take a look at this, predicateForEnablingContact from Apple's documentation
[apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactPickerViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CNContactPickerViewController/predicateForEnablingContact/)

Here is a snippet of code for how I'm using it.

`contactPickerViewController.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count > 0")`

Comment: Yes, this works in UIKit, but in AppKit, the CNContactPicker class counterpart does not appear to have the equivalent predicateForEnablingContact property.  It's almost like they forgot to build it out in AppKit.